# how to synchronize users timezone clocks

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, time, utc

I'm developing a web application (PHP server side )  in which users from all over the world can access. 
Suppose now a user from New York (UTC - 4 ) login to my website (Server is located in Italy (UTC +2 )). When he is logged into it, the server will set a timestamp in that user SQL table with UTC +2.
Suppose now that this user want to get his last time access: he will get a wrong date (6 hours offset due to the different location of the server ).
How can I prevent this unacceptable behavior ? Should I store an UTC offset each time user logs in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly recommended that you store all your timestamps for all your user in a single timezone, which by convention would be UTC.

It will make it much easier to manage the database table, for example sorting users by timestamp.

You can either change the timezone to UTC of your server, of the PHP module or locally in your code.